# What does the leading dash in process cmdline mean?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, shell, process

I noticed a process taking full CPU on my linux server, of which the COMMAND column from `top -c` is `-bash`.

`cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline` shows `-bash` too.

What does the leading dash mean?

More info: I don't know if it's relevant, `/proc/<pid>/exe  -> /bin/bash (deleted)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dash is only relevant to bash (and other shells). It only means that the shell is a login shell.

Comment: I couldn't find this information in manpages for `w` , which uses the same convention while displaying bash login shell, - where is this convention documented in the first place?

Comment: Nevermind, this has been thoroughly addressed in https://superuser.com/a/278865/304718